# warning mysql_query() expects parameter 2 be recourse, object given

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

in a wordpress site, this code gives the following error 
I tried to change it to mysqli, but the same error
anybody has an idea where is the problem, how to deal with.
I searched a lot of answers here but non worked for me.

this code is part of file "class_design.php"

```
function MYORDERS($user_id){

global $wpdb,$PPT, $ThemeDesign, $userdata;
get_currentuserinfo(); 
$content=""; 
$dwl_content=""; 
$td=1; 
$STRING ='<input type="hidden" value="" id="moreinfodiv" name="moreinfodiv">';
$date_format = get_option('date_format') . ' ' . get_option('time_format');
if(!is_numeric($user_id)){ die("nice try!"); }


$SQL = "SELECT * FROM 
       ".$wpdb->prefix."orderdata
       WHERE cus_id='".$userdata->ID."'
       GROUP BY order_id
       ORDER BY autoid DESC";  

$posts = mysql_query($SQL, $wpdb->dbh) or die(mysql_error().' on line: '.__LINE__);

  if ($posts && mysql_num_rows($posts) > 0) {

    while ($thepost = mysql_fetch_object($posts)) { if($thepost->order_total > 0){

    if($thepost->order_status ==0){  
    $status = $PPT->_e(array('myaccount','_paymentstatus0'));
    }elseif($thepost->order_status ==3){ 
    $status = "<b style='color:green;'>".$PPT->_e(array('myaccount','_paymentstatus1'))."</b>";
    }elseif($thepost->order_status ==5){ 
    $status = "<b style='color:green;'>".$PPT->_e(array('myaccount','_paymentstatus2'))."</b>";
    }elseif($thepost->order_status ==6){  
    $status = "<b style='color:red;'>".$PPT->_e(array('myaccount','_paymentstatus3'))."</b>";
    }elseif($thepost->order_status ==7){ 
    $status = "<b style='color:blue;'>".$PPT->_e(array('myaccount','_paymentstatus4'))."</b>";
    }elseif($thepost->order_status ==8){ 
    $status = "<b>".$PPT->_e(array('myaccount','_paymentstatus5'))."</b>";
    }
```

[image: error appears in the page]

Comment: I was going to flag this as a duplicate but there are so many questions like this I couldn't decide which one... so I'll just plop the obligatory **stop using the deprecated `mysql_` extension** notice instead : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: I appreciate that for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a `$wpdb` object to `mysql_query` which expects a resource, meaning a mysql connection.

Try to use the `$wpdb` object directly like so:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM 
       ".$wpdb->prefix."orderdata
       WHERE cus_id='".$userdata->ID."' 
       GROUP BY order_id 
       ORDER BY autoid DESC";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($SQL);

foreach ($posts as $post) {

    // do your business here

}
```